# Redis cli shell script unknown operand deleting keys with hex

Tags: bash, shell-script, redis

Created a shell script that deletes keys that matches a pattern using the following script:

```
host=${1:-}
port=${2:-6379}
database=${3:-0}
pattern=${4:-"Test"}

cursor=-1
keys=""

echo "Starting to delete"
while [ $cursor -ne 0 ]; do
  if [ $cursor -eq -1 ]
  then
    cursor=0
  fi

  reply=`redis-cli -h $host -p $port SCAN $cursor MATCH $pattern`
  cursor=`expr "$reply" : '\([0-9]*[0-9 ]\)'`
  keys=${reply##[0-9]*[0-9 ]}
  echo "$keys"
  redis-cli -h $host -p $port DEL $keys
done
```

This is working fine for keys that doesn't have hex in keys. But when keys with hex characters involved, encountered an unknown operand error message.
Sample key:

```
\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x15test
```

Need suggestions on how to escape these characters.

The same problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854691/how-to-delete-redis-keys-with-special-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to quote the keys

```
redis-cli -h $host -p $port DEL "$keys"
```

That should suffice. Without the quotes, the backslashes may be interpreted differently. It may also be necessary to double the backslashes. You could use `sed` for that.

```
redis-cli -h $host -p $port DEL `echo "$keys" | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/'`
```

The shell is likely transforming "\x" into just "x".

Comment: when using sed ��ttestERR wrong number of arguments for 'del' command

Comment: You can try to run that `echo "$keys" | sed -e 's/\\/\\\\/'` on its own... to see that the output is correct.

Comment: this is the output `��ttest`. Is it because of this weird characters?

Comment: So the hex characters were already transformed to characters/bytes. I'm not too sure how you'd deal with that.

Comment: Yes. I updated the question and added link to similar issue. Suggestion is to use different client. I'll try to python instead

Comment: still accepted as an answer because the question is about hex and this answer provides solution for that scenario